# Repeating string inside loop

Tags: java, string, loops, split

I'm trying to read a `contact name`, `email` and `mobile number` from file(i.e contact.txt) using split function. So i captured all those strings into array using `\n` and `"<space>"`.

Inside my file `contact.txt`, data is followed as below:

```
name1 email1 mobile_1
name2 email2 mobile_2
name3 email3 mobile_3
name4 email4 mobile_4
name5 email5 mobile_5
name6 email6 mobile_6
```

Here is my code looks like:

```
String usersInfo;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/contact.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    usersInfo = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}


String[] splitStrNewLine = usersInfo.split("\n");
String[] splitStrSpace = usersInfo.split("[ \n]");


for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<=2; j++){
        System.out.println(splitStrSpace[j]);
    }
}
```

Now it started giving the output same string with repeating loop wise, Output as followed:

```
name1
email1
mobile_1

name1
email1
mobile_1

name1
email1
mobile_1

name1
email1
mobile_1

name1
email1
mobile_1

name1
email1
mobile_1
```

Please let me know, How to retrieve my all data series wise?

Help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: The loop at the bottom doesn't seem to use the `i` index at all

Comment: What should i use in that case?

Comment: Why don't you just split the contact info inside the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after the try block

```
String[] splitStrNewLine = usersInfo.split("\n");

fileLength = splitStrNewLine.length();

for(int i=0; i<fileLength; i++){
    splitStrSpace = splitStrNewLine[i].split("[ ]"); \\specify delimiter you want to split
    for(int j=0; j<splitStrSpace.length(); j++){
        System.out.println(splitStrSpace[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can i recommend you go ahead and use a real collection structure?  You are using readLine to get lines.  Why paste them back together with a character inserted that then needs to be parsed out again?

```
List<String> usersInfo = new ArrayList<String>()
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/contact.txt"));
try {
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        lines.add(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Now you have a structure that is easy to iterate, and you get each line back the same as it came in.  Now, just iterate the lines, and split each line as needed:

```
for(String line : userInfo){
    String[] splitStrSpace = line.split("[ ]");
    for(int j=0; j<=splitStrSpace.length; j++){
        System.out.println(splitStrSpace[j]);
    }
}
```